# Typeahead.js not render any suggestions

Tags: typeahead.js

I have problem with Typeahead.js. I'm using 'remote' parameter to get data from server. It look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#search').typeahead({
    name: 'find-persons',
    remote: '/project/index.php/person/search/query/%QUERY',
    limit: 10,
    template: '<p>{{name}} {{surname}} #{{value}}</p>',
    engine: Hogan
});
```

});

this is JSON response from server

```
 [
    {'value': '1', 'tokens': ['1', 'John', 'Nhoj'], 'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Nhoj'},
    {'value': '2', 'tokens': ['2', 'Jane', 'Enaj'], 'name': 'Jane', 'surname': 'Enaj'},
 ]
```

but it's not rendering any suggestions. When I put JSON to parameter 'local' it works correctly.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `valueKey` property to whichever key you want to search on (name or surname)?